# Angular 2 named outlets redirect to

Tags: angular

I want to redirect on empty string to the three outlets below. Normally if I wanted to redirectTo cow-group for example I would just put that. Is there an obvious way to do this I'm not seeing?

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'cow-group',
        component: GroupSelector,
        outlet: 'comp1'
    },
    {
        path: 'cow-group',
        component: TraitSelector,
        outlet: 'comp2'
    },
    {
        path:
        'cow-group',
        component: CowTable,
        outlet: 'comp3'
    }
];
```

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12740

Comment: I dont think that's a real bug, probably just a mistake in code. I can just change a few things and get a match. I cannot match the outlets though.